# Arranging factors in increasing order

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to create two plots which should display frequency in a decreasing order.

```
#preparing the data to resemble actual data
test <- data.frame(HairEyeColor) %>%
  mutate(combi = paste(Hair,Eye)) %>%
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  mutate(prop = Freq / sum(Freq))  %>%
  ungroup() 
test$combi <- factor(test$combi)
freq_test_count <- test %>%
  setorder(Freq)

#creating the plot
freq_test_plot <- freq_test_count %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(combi,prop),y = prop, label = Freq)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, nudge_y = 0.005, size = 3) + 
  facet_wrap(~Sex, scales = "free") +
  labs(y = "Proportion",
       x = NULL) +
  coord_flip()
```

When i plot freq_test_plot, it shows the plot but the [output is not in decreasing order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARb5Z.jpg)

I am not sure what should I do so that I can see terms in decreasing order of frequency.

[image]

Comment: Looks to be in overall decreasing order. Do you mean that you want the scales in different orders for males and females? That sounds potentially misleading as it will take a careful observer to realize the labels are in different orders.

Comment: The idea is to show that the labels are in different orders for males and females. 

I am not sure how the order is being decided here. I cant figure out why "Blond Blue" 30 is before "Brown Blue" 50.

Comment: Your ordering ignored sex. Blond Blue has a total of 30 + 64 = 94, so it is ahead of Brown Blue which is 50 + 34 = 84. I think this chart is useful because it orders by the overall population, and where the bars for a particular sex are not in order it highlights the differences between the sexes. The chart you are asking for makes it much harder to compare the sex differences because you have to switch back and forth reading and comparing the labels.

Comment: For example, this version makes it obvious that the Blond Blue combination is far more common for women than for men - it jumps out as soon as you look at the chart. The charts in the answers, however, hide that insight unless you read them carefully. Similarly, the chart in your question shows that Brown Blue is more common than for women, but if you glanced at the charts in the answers I would assume the labels are in the same order and since the distributions look about the same I would conclude there is no real difference between male and female distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to create two different plots and arrange them in grid. But you should be cautious because, [like Gregor mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083750/arranging-factors-in-increasing-order#comment83142892_48083750), it could definitely be misleading.

```
library(grid)
p1 = freq_test_count[freq_test_count$Sex == "Male",] %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(combi,prop),y = prop, label = Freq)) +
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, nudge_y = 0.005, size = 3) + 
    facet_wrap(~Sex, scales = "free") +
    labs(y = "Proportion",
         x = NULL) +
    coord_flip()

p2 = freq_test_count[freq_test_count$Sex == "Female",] %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(combi,prop),y = prop, label = Freq)) +
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, nudge_y = 0.005, size = 3) + 
    facet_wrap(~Sex, scales = "free") +
    labs(y = "Proportion",
         x = NULL) +
    coord_flip()

graphics.off()
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I hoped I wont have to add another library as the code might be shared with others. But seems this is the only way. I will accept this as answer if nothing better comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Another work-around is to make male and female specific levels for the factor. Here I add a space `" "` to the front of the Male Hair/Eye labels. This lets you define an ordering that takes sex into account:

```
test <- data.frame(HairEyeColor) %>%
  mutate(combi = paste(Hair,Eye)) %>%
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  mutate(prop = Freq / sum(Freq))  %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(combi = factor(test$combi),
         sex_combi = factor(paste(ifelse(Sex == "Male", " ", ""), Hair, Eye)),
         sex_combi = reorder(sex_combi, prop))

#creating the plot

ggplot(test, aes(x = sex_combi,y = prop, label = Freq)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, nudge_y = 0.005, size = 3) + 
  facet_wrap(~Sex, scales = "free") +
  labs(y = "Proportion",
       x = NULL) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

But as I mentioned in the comments, I think this is a misleading plot.

Comment: Thanks. I will check if introducing a leading character in my actual data would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the values to be sorted on male or female?

```
library(tidyverse)

#preparing the data to resemble actual data
test <- data.frame(HairEyeColor) %>%
  mutate(combi = paste(Hair,Eye)) %>%
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  mutate(prop = Freq / sum(Freq))  %>%
  ungroup() 
test$combi <- factor(test$combi)


test$combi<- factor(test$combi, levels = unique(test$combi)[order(test$Freq)],)

#creating the plot

  ggplot(test,aes(x = combi,y = prop, label = Freq))+
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, nudge_y = 0.005, size = 3) + 
  facet_wrap(~Sex, scales = "free")+ 
  labs(y = "Proportion",
   x = NULL) +
  coord_flip()
```

updated to include full code from question.

Comment: This doesn't produce a sorted bar chart for me.

Comment: Agree with @Gregor. This code doesn't produce a sorted bar chart for me.

Comment: The point of the chart is to show sorting by male or female, not both male and female. Running the code will show male sorted in descending order.